# call a property inside the class which is coming after the page is loaded

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, highcharts

I am using `angular-highcharts` implementation of `highcharts` in my angular application. In this, I took a example

```
    chart = new Chart({
         chart: {
            type: 'spline',
            events: {
                click: (e) => {
            this.getCategory(this.chart.ref.series[0].searchPoint(e, true).category);
                }
            }
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Monthly Average Temperature'
        },
        subtitle: {
            text: 'Source: WorldClimate.com'
        },
        xAxis: {
            categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun',
                'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
        },
        yAxis: {
            title: {
                text: 'Temperature'
            }
        },
        tooltip: {
            crosshairs: true,
            shared: true
        },
        plotOptions: {
            spline: {
                marker: {
                    radius: 4,
                    lineColor: '#666666',
                    lineWidth: 1
                }
            }
        },
        series: [{
            name: 'Tokyo',
            data: [7.0, 6.9, 9.5, 14.5, 18.2, 21.5, 25.2, 26.5, 23.3, 18.3, 13.9, 9.6]

        }, {
            name: 'London',
            data: [3.9, 4.2, 5.7, 8.5, 11.9, 15.2, 17.0, 16.6, 14.2, 10.3, 6.6, 4.8]
        }]

    })
```

If you look at the chart property inside chart object

```
chart: {
            type: 'spline',
            events: {
                click: (e) => {
            this.getCategory(this.chart.ref.series[0].searchPoint(e, true).category);
                }
            }
        }
```

I am binding a click event to the method `getCategory(category : any)` present inside my component.

Now the issue is, when I am calling `this.chart.ref.series[0].searchPoint(e,true)` it is giving error in the IDE says "property 'searchPoint()' does not exist on type 'chart' " but when I run it into the web browser with this error, its working fine. `searchPoint()` method exist in the chart object when the angular view is completely loaded.

Now, how to remove this error "property does not exist" from the component. I tried using bracket notation but that doesn't worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

why don't you write the event in "ngAfterViewInIt"

if you use this lifecycle method it will load after component view is completely loaded

Comment: Its working fine in browser either I'm declaring chart object in class or calling in any method or lifecycle hook. My issue is its giving error in my IDE that searchPoint() doesn't exist in the type chart